# Iptables/Route with 2 ssid hostapd and subnets and openvpn setup

Tags: linux, networking, routing, iptables, openvpn

I'm struggling to setup iptables/routing in the correct way.

Objective is:
- Traffic from clients connected to wifi-KK to not use the tunnel but go via eth0 to router
- Traffic from clients connected to wifi-KK-VPN to use tunnel

I think this needs amendment of iptables and probably different routes as well as override the ones passed down from openvpn.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

I have a network setup as follows:

Router: 192.168.0.1 (Virgin default) with wifi ssid VMxxx

Server:
eth0: 191.168.0.254 (in same network as router)
wlan0: 192.168.101.1 (wi-fi network for clients using VPN secured connection)
wlan0_0: 191.168.102.1 (wi-fi network for regular connection)
tun0: openvpn tunnel

(output ifconfig below)

Both wifi networks are running DHCP Servers as follows:

```
subnet 192.168.101.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
range 192.168.101.10 192.168.101.50;
option broadcast-address 192.168.101.255;
option routers 192.168.101.1;
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
option domain-name "local";
option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;
}

subnet 192.168.102.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
range 192.168.102.10 192.168.102.50;
option broadcast-address 192.168.102.255;
option routers 192.168.102.1;
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
option domain-name "local2";
option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;
}
```

Hostapd is running two ssids on one NIC (output below)

Iptables: and routes:

```
    root@odroidc1-001e06101641:~# cat /etc/iptables.ipv4.nat
    #Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Wed May 27 11:41:17 2015

*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [9:496]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [13:1488]
-A FORWARD -s 192.168.101.0/24 -i wlan0 -o eth0 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m comment --comment "Block traffic from clients to eth0" -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -s 192.168.101.0/24 -i wlan0 -o tun0 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m comment --comment "Allow only traffic from clients to tun0" -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed May 27 11:41:17 2015
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Wed May 27 11:41:17 2015
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -m comment --comment "Use VPN IP for eth0" -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -m comment --comment "Use VPN IP for tun0" -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed May 27 11:41:17 2015
root@odroidc1-001e06101641:~# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.10.100.9     128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
default         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.10.100.1     10.10.100.9     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 tun0
10.10.100.9     *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
91.109.241.36.s 192.168.0.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
128.0.0.0       10.10.100.9     128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.101.0   *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.102.0   *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0_0
```

ifconfig:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1e:06:10:16:41
          inet addr:192.168.0.254  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::21e:6ff:fe10:1641/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:9584376 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6015092 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:4173640561 (3.8 GiB)  TX bytes:2116013071 (1.9 GiB)
          Interrupt:40

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:163 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:163 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:31514 (30.7 KiB)  TX bytes:31514 (30.7 KiB)

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet addr:10.10.100.10  P-t-P:10.10.100.9  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:5141382 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4101062 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100
          RX bytes:205969325 (196.4 MiB)  TX bytes:1000934406 (954.5 MiB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:3a:35:d0:36:90
          inet addr:192.168.101.1  Bcast:192.168.101.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::3a:35ff:fed0:3690/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:5947384 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:7650191 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:1402507838 (1.3 GiB)  TX bytes:3212528188 (2.9 GiB)

wlan0_0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:3a:35:d0:36:91
          inet addr:192.168.102.1  Bcast:192.168.102.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::3a:35ff:fed0:3691/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:588 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:703 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:71131 (69.4 KiB)  TX bytes:214448 (209.4 KiB)
```

hostapd:

```
root@odroidc1-001e06101641:~# cat /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
# interface
interface=wlan0
# new mac
bssid=02:3a:35:d0:36:90
# driver
driver=nl80211
# CTRL-Interface
ctrl_interface=/var/run/hostapd
ctrl_interface_group=0
# SSID
ssid=wifi-KK-VPN
# WLAN
country_code=KR
hw_mode=g
channel=1
beacon_int=100
dtim_period=2
max_num_sta=255
rts_threshold=2347
fragm_threshold=2346
preamble=1
# Logging
logger_syslog=-1
logger_syslog_level=3
logger_stdout=-1
logger_stdout_level=2
# passphrase
wpa_passphrase=
# WPA2
wpa=3
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
beacon_int=100
auth_algs=3
# 1=wpa, 2=wep, 3=both macaddr_acl=0
wmm_enabled=1
eap_reauth_period=360000000
#rsn_preauth=1
#rsn_preauth_interfaces=wlan0
wpa_group_rekey=600
wpa_ptk_rekey=600
wpa_gmk_rekey=86400

##### new wifi
bss=wlan0_0
ssid=wifi-KK
# WLAN
##country_code=KR
##hw_mode=g
##channel=1
##beacon_int=100
##dtim_period=2
##max_num_sta=255
##rts_threshold=2347
##fragm_threshold=2346
##preamble=1
# Logging
logger_syslog=-1
logger_syslog_level=3
logger_stdout=-1
logger_stdout_level=2
# passphrase
wpa_passphrase=
# WPA2
wpa=3
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
beacon_int=100
auth_algs=3
# 1=wpa, 2=wep, 3=both macaddr_acl=0
##wmm_enabled=1
##eap_reauth_period=360000000
#rsn_preauth=1
#rsn_preauth_interfaces=wlan0
##wpa_group_rekey=600
##wpa_ptk_rekey=600
##wpa_gmk_rekey=86400
```